# Conditionals in handlebars

Tags: javascript, css, templates, handlebars.js

I want to add a class on a div based on part of my data set(JSON). This is what I have 
data:

```
{
    "title":"energy star",

    "cat":"power",

    "diff":"Investment",
    "description":"When purchasing appliances, consider buying 'energystar' certified appliances to radically reduce the amount of electricity used by older appliances.",
    "links":[
        {
            "title":"The Official Website of Energystar",
            "url":"http://www.energystar.gov"
        }
    ],
    "cost":"$60+"
},
{
    "title":"shut the faucet",
    "cat":"water",
    "diff":"No-Cost",
    "description":"Turn off the water while you brush your teeth. There is never a good reason for waste.",
    "cost":"$0"
},`
```

Here is my template

```
        {{#each this}}
        {{#addClasses}}
        {{/addClasses}}

        <div class="tip_whole">
            <div class="tip_header">
                <h5 class="tip_title">
                    <b>{{title}}</b> - {{diff}}
                </h5>
                <div class="tip_social">
                    <a href=""><img src="IMG/media/twitter_16.png" alt="twiter link"/></a>
                    <a href=""><img src="IMG/media/facebook_16.png" alt="facebook link"/></a>
                    <a href=""><img src="IMG/media/email_16.png" alt="email link"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>{{!end .tip_title}}
            <div class="tip_body">
                <div class="grid_20 alpha">
                    <p class="tip_desc">{{description}}</p>
                    {{#if links}}
                        <div class="tip_links">
                        <h5>More information</h5>
                        {{#each links}}
                                <a href="{{url}}" class="tip_link" target="_blank">{{title}}</a>
                        {{/each}}
                        </div>{{!end .tip_links}}
                    {{/if}}
                </div>{{!end .grid_20 alpha}}
                <div class="grid_19 push_2">
                    <h2 class="tip_cost_title">Avg. Cost to Implement</h2>
                    <h1 class="tip_cost_title">{{cost}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>{{!end .tip_body}}
        </div>{{!end .tip_whole}}
    {{/each}}
```

and this is my helper function

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("addClasses",function(){
    if(this.cat=="water"){
            console.log('water');
            $(".tip_whole").addClass("water");
        } else {
            console.log('no water here');
        }
});//end of helper function
```

It properly logs that there is water but it will never add the class, it will only affect the '.tip_whole' that is hardcoded but it will not affect the ones created by handlebars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That helper won't work because `.tip_whole` isn't in the DOM when you say `$(".tip_whole")` so you end up adding your `water` class to nothing at all. You're going to have to change your helper to return a class (or nothing) as a string:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("addClasses", function() {
    return this.cat == 'water' ? 'water' : '';
});
```

and then use that helper where you want the class:

```
<div class="tip_whole {{addClasses}}">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SSPSY/